# regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here is a part of the data

```
Broan Range Hood (BP130WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (BP130BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (GP124WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (GP130WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS130WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS130BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (QS130SSN) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (QS230WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS230BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (QS230SSN) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (QS330WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS330BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (QS330SSN) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (E66130SSL) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (RM503004) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (273003) - Stainless
```

I want to remove `(RM503004)`, `(273003)` which could be 3 to 11 alphanumeric codes wrapped inside `()`

Using Python I can use it like below:

```
text = re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,11}', ' ', dataset['Title'][i])
```

but the output of that isn't as desired, which would be:

```
Broan Range Hood  - White
Broan Range Hood  - Black
Broan Range Hood  - White
Broan Range Hood  - White
Broan Range Hood  - White
Broan Range Hood  - Black
Broan Range Hood  - Stainless
Broan Range Hood  - White
Broan Range Hood  - Black
Broan Range Hood  - Stainless
Broan Range Hood  - White
Broan Range Hood  - Black
Broan Range Hood  - Stainless
Broan Range Hood  - Stainless
Broan Range Hood  - Stainless
Broan Range Hood  - Stainless
```

Comment: `\([^)]*\)` ..............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close, just add the escaped parentheses:

```
\([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,11}\)\s*
```

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
Broan Range Hood (BP130WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (BP130BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (GP124WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (GP130WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS130WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS130BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (QS130SSN) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (QS230WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS230BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (QS230SSN) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (QS330WWN) - White
Broan Range Hood (QS330BLN) - Black
Broan Range Hood (QS330SSN) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (E66130SSL) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (RM503004) - Stainless
Broan Range Hood (273003) - Stainless

'''

expression = r'\([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,11}\)\s*'

print(re.sub(expression, '', string))
```

#### Output

```
Broan Range Hood - White
Broan Range Hood - Black
Broan Range Hood - White
Broan Range Hood - White
Broan Range Hood - White
Broan Range Hood - Black
Broan Range Hood - Stainless
Broan Range Hood - White
Broan Range Hood - Black
Broan Range Hood - Stainless
Broan Range Hood - White
Broan Range Hood - Black
Broan Range Hood - Stainless
Broan Range Hood - Stainless
Broan Range Hood - Stainless
Broan Range Hood - Stainless
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9MNE8r/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/9MNE8r/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

Answer (score 2):

You need to also match on literal brackets, which need escaping with a backslash.

To keep the whitespace looking good, match surrounding whitespace too, then replace with a space:

```
text = re.sub('\s*\([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,11}\)\s*', ' ', dataset['Title'][i])
```